# WebService complex-type returns empty after deploying

Tags: java, android, web-services

I have an android application using ksoap2.
Also a webservice running on tomcat (axis2)

There is a method on the webservice returning:

```
    public class RecipeSmallReturnType 
{
    public int      mId;
    public String   mName;
    public String   mDescription;
    public String   mUsername;
    public int      mDifficulty;
    public int      mServeCount;
    public int      mPreparationTime;
    public float    mTotalRating;
    public int      mNumOfVotes;
    public int      mOwnerId;
    public int      mUserRating;
    public int      mNumOfViews;
    public String   mReleaseDate;
}
```

In the client (android using ksoap2) I have same class implementing KvmSerliazable

```
    public class RecipeSmallReturnType implements KvmSerializable
{
    public int      mId;
    public String   mName;
    public String   mDescription;
    public String   mUsername;
    public int      mDifficulty;
    public int      mServeCount;
    public int      mPreparationTime;
    public float    mTotalRating;
    public int      mNumOfVotes;
    public int      mOwnerId;
    public int      mUserRating;
    public int      mNumOfViews;
    public String   mReleaseDate;

    public Object getProperty( int param ) 
    {
        switch( param )
        {
            case 0:     return new Integer( mId );
            case 1:     return mName;
            case 2:     return mDescription;
            case 3:     return mUsername;
            case 4:     return new Integer( mDifficulty );
            case 5:     return new Integer( mServeCount );
            case 6:     return new Integer( mPreparationTime );
            case 7:     return new Float( mTotalRating );
            case 8:     return new Integer( mNumOfVotes );
            case 9:     return new Integer( mOwnerId );
            case 10:    return new Integer( mUserRating );
            case 11:    return new Integer( mNumOfViews );
            case 12:    return mReleaseDate;

            default:    return null;
        }
    }

    public int getPropertyCount() 

{
    return 13;
}

public void getPropertyInfo( int param, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo arg2) 
{
    switch( param )
    {
        case 0:
            arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name   = "mId";
            break;

        case 1:
            arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            arg2.name   = "mName";
            break;

        case 2:
            arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            arg2.name   = "mDescription";
            break;

        case 3:
            arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            arg2.name   = "mUsername";
            break;

        case 4:
            arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name   = "mDifficulty";
            break;

        case 5:
            arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name   = "mServeCount";
            break;

        case 6:
            arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name   = "mPreparationTime";
            break;

        case 7:
            arg2.type   = Float.class;
            arg2.name   = "mTotalRating";
            break;

        case 8:
            arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name   = "mNumOfVotes";
            break;

        case 9:
            arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name   = "mOwnerId";
            break;

        case 10:
            arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name   = "mUserRating";
            break;

        case 11:
            arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
            arg2.name   = "mNumOfViews";
            break;

        case 12:
            arg2.type   = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            arg2.name   = "mReleaseDate";
            break;

        default:    break;
    }
}

public void setProperty( int param, Object obj ) 
{
    switch( param )
    {
        case 0:     mId                 = (Integer)obj; break;
        case 1:     mName               = (String)obj;  break;
        case 2:     mDescription        = (String)obj;  break;
        case 3:     mUsername           = (String)obj;  break;
        case 4:     mDifficulty         = (Integer)obj; break;
        case 5:     mServeCount         = (Integer)obj; break;
        case 6:     mPreparationTime    = (Integer)obj; break;
        case 7:     mTotalRating        = (Float)obj;   break;
        case 8:     mNumOfVotes         = (Integer)obj; break;
        case 9:     mOwnerId            = (Integer)obj; break;
        case 10:    mUserRating         = (Integer)obj; break;
        case 11:    mNumOfViews         = (Integer)obj; break;
        case 12:    mReleaseDate        = (String)obj;  break;

            default:    return;
        }
    }
}
```

If I run the webservice localy (using new->Web service-> etc. in the eclipse) I get the return parameter (an array filled with data) as supposed to.
But - after deploying on the webserice I do not get the data.

```
searchRecipesNewResponse{return=RecipeSmallReturnType{}; return=RecipeSmallReturnType{}; }
```

Why does it happen after deployment?
How can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the proper url in your android app and is that domain accessible e.g. in the browser on the phone?